# Catching some errors in interceptor

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm using an interceptor to handle unauthorised HTTP requests, which will either show a modal or route to the login page. When the interceptor handles the error I don't want the service or component that made the original request to handle the error as well. I do want the component or services error handling to kick in for any errors which are not 401s.

In my interceptor I'm catching the error with RxJS `catchError` and checking the error details. Where it's not going to be handled by the interceptor I'm just re-throwing it with `throwError` which seems to work okay. The problem is where I need to stop the error propagating. If I return nothing I get the following error:

> ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected.
>   You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

Returning an empty observable using `of()` almost works, but I get the following error in the console when the application loads.

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): EmptyError: no elements in sequence

I can't work out why, or how to fix it. How should I terminate execution in an interceptor, essentially completing the observable?  Here's my code:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor (
    private router: Router,
    private sessionService: SessionService
  ) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    request = request.clone()
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError((err: any) => {
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          if (err.status === 401 && this.router.url === '/') {
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/login')
          } else if (err.status === 401 && !/^\/activate-account/.test(this.router.url) && !/^\/log-?[i,I]n/.test(this.router.url)) {
            this.sessionService.setSessionExpired()  
          }
          return of()
        } else {
          return throwError(err)
        }
      })
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems like returning an empty observable after navigating is causing the problem. I've removed the `return of()` line and instead added specific returns for the if conditions. After `navigateByUrl` I've added `return throwError(err)` and after `setSessionExpired` I've added `return EMPTY`. I'm not sure why this fixes it. If anyone can explain why this works that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was due to navigating away before returning an empty observable. I've moved the return statements into the specific if conditions so I can return `throwError(err)` after calling `this.router.navigateByUrl`, otherwise I return an empty observable. I'm also using the `EMPTY` observable constant (as suggested by Suresh Kumar Ariya)

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor (
    private router: Router,
    private sessionService: SessionService
  ) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    request = request.clone()
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError((err: any) => {
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          if (err.status === 401 && this.router.url === '/') {
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/login')
            return throwError(err)
          } else if (err.status === 401 && !/^\/activate-account/.test(this.router.url) && !/^\/log-?[i,I]n/.test(this.router.url)) {
            this.sessionService.setSessionExpired()
            return EMPTY
          } else {
            return throwError(err)
          }
        } else {
          return throwError(err)
        }
      })
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you try Observable.empty(). Which will stop propagation and return the handler back to the calling service.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor (
    private router: Router,
    private sessionService: SessionService
  ) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    request = request.clone()
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError((err: any) => {
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          if (err.status === 401 && this.router.url === '/') {
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/login')
          } else if (err.status === 401 && !/^\/activate-account/.test(this.router.url) && !/^\/log-?[i,I]n/.test(this.router.url)) {
            this.sessionService.setSessionExpired()  
          }
          return Observable.empty();
        } else {
          return throwError(err)
        }
      })
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between `empty()` and `of()`? Either way I still get the `EmptyError` when initially loading the app.

Comment: You can use Of(null) and empty(). Both will complete the observable and return the value.

Comment: From the official rxjs docs:

Observable.empty()

Creates an Observable that emits no items to the Observer and immediately emits a complete notification.

Observable.of()

Creates an Observable that emits some values you specify as arguments, immediately one after the other, and then emits a complete notification.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, the empty observable isn't something I've seen before but is really useful. I'm using RXJS6 so in this case it's just `empty()` or `EMPTY` rather than `Observable.empty()`. It looks like the problem was returning an empty observable after navigating, but I'm not sure why that causes a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The interceptor expects a return statement that you transfer with `catchError`. If you don't, you don't respect the signature of the interceptor, thus your error.

To avoid that, always return a thrown observable. You can return `throwError(undefined)`, and in your error handling, if you see the error is undefined, you simply don't treat it. You can even go further and use Rx to filter the undefined errors with `.pipe(filter(err => !!err))`.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is on the right track. I'd like to avoid putting specific error handling for the undefined error on every HTTP request as it's going to be a headache to maintain. Each future project will need to remember to check for undefined errors. and let's face it, people don't read documentation.
Also, the filter doesn't run for errors. Is there an error equivalent that can be used to filter only errors as I could then tack that onto the pipe in the interceptor and will only need it in one place?

Comment: You're right it doesn't exist. But there's a solution you can [**see here**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7w9lu2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts) (change `false` to `true`)

Comment: And about treating errors in your component, given your code you won't, since you redirect or set expired session.